# elasticsearch sort by a field name in a get request not working

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm trying to sort a result like this one:

```
{
hits: {total: {value: 192, relation: "eq"}, max_score: 2.4924624,…}
hits: [
{
  _id: "6501467",
  _index: "nomenclator",
  _score: 2.4924624,
  atc: "M01AE01",
  valorUnidadEnvase: "200",
},
{
  _id: "6501467",
  _index: "nomenclator",
  _score: 2.4924624,
  atc: "M01AE01",
  valorUnidadEnvase: "20",
},
{
  _id: "6501467",
  _index: "nomenclator",
  _score: 2.4924624,
  atc: "M01AE01",
  valorUnidadEnvase: "30",
}
]
...
```

This is just a fast example, the real one has to much fields.

I want to sort by "valorUnidadEnvase" in "asc", I'm trying it using a get request and the next query:

```
q: atc:M01*
size: 10
sort: [{"valorUnidadEnvase":{"order":"asc"}}]
```

But I'm not getting a sorted result

What am I ignoring or what do I need to sort this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your mapping, you need to define `valorUnidadEnvase` as [Numeric field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html)**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "valorUnidadEnvase": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
     "atc": "M01AE01",
  "valorUnidadEnvase": "30"
}
{
     "atc": "M01AE01",
  "valorUnidadEnvase": "200"
}
{
     "atc": "M01AE01",
  "valorUnidadEnvase": "20"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "valorUnidadEnvase": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "66985849",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "atc": "M01AE01",
      "valorUnidadEnvase": "20"
    },
    "sort": [
      20
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index": "66985849",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "atc": "M01AE01",
      "valorUnidadEnvase": "30"
    },
    "sort": [
      30
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index": "66985849",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "atc": "M01AE01",
      "valorUnidadEnvase": "200"
    },
    "sort": [
      200
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: it works after create the index mapping, thanks!